# Isomorphism between cellular and simplicial homology of Klein bottle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Denote the Klein bottle by $K$. I can compute that$$\pi_1(K) \cong \langle a, b \mid ab = ba^{-1}\rangle, \quad H_0(K) = \mathbb{Z}, \quad H_1(K) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \quad H_2(K) = 0.$$**Question.** What is a description of the isomorphism between the cellular and simplicial homology specifically here?

[Alejo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/144221/alejo) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1983538/373012) writes the following.

> As for simplicial homology, whenever you have a triangulation, it is a particular case of cellular decomposition, and the corresponding cellular chain complex will be literally the same thing as the simplicial chain complex. This identification is tautological...

I was wondering if anybody could spell it out explicitly in the case of the Klein bottle here though?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me: Do you understand that a triangulation *is* a cellular decomposition of the space? So for every triangulation, you get a cellular decomposition which computes, by definition, the same homology. This is indeed tautological, as Alejo said.

Comment: In the cellular chain complex, $C_n^{CW} (X)$ is freely generated by the $n$-cells, and the differentials are $\sum_j d_{ij} \, e_j^{(n-1)}$ where the multiplicities $d_{ij}$ are the degrees of your attaching maps. When you deal with a triangulation, the $n$-simplices are your $n$-cells, and the multiplicities $d_{ij}$ are $\pm 1$, depending on orientations. (Normally the orientations are induced from some order on vertices, in such a way that you get alternating sums $d [v_0,\ldots,v_n] = \sum_i (-1)^i \, [v_0,\ldots,\hat{v}_i,\ldots,v_n]$.)

Comment: So when you pick a triangulation and write down the complex for simplicial homology (there are different ways to define it, but I guess you are reading Hatcher's book, so I refer to his "$\Delta$-complex" stuff), you are basically writing down the cellular chain complex.